# In Box2D, a Body that causes player to bounce, but object does not bounce itself

Tags: box2d, game-physics

I have a `Box2D` `World` which contains 10 `Bodies`.
1 `Body` is `STATIC`, which is the ground, the rest are all `DYNAMIC`. They are all `Rectangle`s, with varying dimensions.
1 `Rectangle` acts as the `Player`, when you press left/right that body moves and you can use space bar to jump.

All objects have a `restitution` of `0.3f`, which I feel is realistic.
When the `Player` lands after jumping, they gradually loose speed and remain on the ground as though they're standing. This is the behaviour if `Player` lands on any of the other `bodies` in the `World`.

Id like to be able to define a new object, a `Spring`. 
When the `Player` jumps on it, they are projected into the air with same force that they landed on it with e.g using restitution of `1.0f`
However, If the `Spring` falls off a cliff, I don't want it to bounce.

What would be a suitable way to implement this?

Comment: When player hits specifically that kind of bouncing objects you can give ApplyForce on that Player object..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this in the end ..

```
public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {

        if (contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData() instanceof Spring){

            float impulse = contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getMass() * impulseToApply; 

            contact.getFixtureB().getBody().applyLinearImpulse( 
                    new Vec2(0, impulse), 
                    contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getWorldCenter() );

        }else if (contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getUserData() instanceof Spring){

            float impulse = contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getMass() * impulseToApply; 

            contact.getFixtureA().getBody().applyLinearImpulse( 
                    new Vec2(0, impulse), 
                    contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getWorldCenter() );
        }
    }
```